# How to find and disable a content control by tag to delete it and its contents?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the unfortunate task of being forced to design a Word-based electronic production card for the unit at my company, even though I've never worked with VBA. I would much rather have done this in Excel since I wouldn't have to wrestle with content control and hard-to-find locations in various tables over the pages, but the company's documentation-system forces this particular one to be in Word.

My issue is that for proper form of the production card I need to use tables, and I need the production card to be dynamic to limit its size to what operations that are relevant for a specific order. My chosen solution is to create a full form, and to use a user form/prompt where they can choose which parts to use and which parts to ommit, and the ommitted ones will then be deleted. Part of reason for the solution is because that is how their previous (and Excel-based) production card works, so it would make it more familiar for the end user.

Because MS Word is finicky I need to use content control within these tables to not have the end user accidentally destroy half of it, but after a full workday I still cannot figure out how find and shut off the content control of the cells in tables that I want to delete. I do have the content controls tagged since that seems like the only reasonable way to find them.

This is my current code for the subprocedure, but for some reason I cannot get the ID through the ccID line, even though I have verified that the string supplied as argument is correct.

```
Private Sub DeleteCCByTag(ccTag As String)
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Dim ccID As String
    ccID = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag(ccTag).Item(1).ID
    'MsgBox ccID        'Debug prompt
    Set cc = ThisDocument.ContentControls(ccID)
    cc.LockContentControl = False
    cc.LockContents = False
    cc.Delete (False)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this Sub actually in the Document that you are trying to process? AS a quick sanity check, you can change ThisDocument to ActiveDocument, ensure that your document is the active document, and try again.

Comment: I had accidentally saved the document with the content control successfully removed, but an identical error message because of a whitespace problem with another CC, so it seems like my code actually worked after all. Thank you for trying to help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all- your code is working find for me but...

1. `ContentControls tag` is case-sensitive which could be a problem in your situation
2. You could solve your problem without searching for ID value in this way:

   ```
   Private Sub DeleteCCByTag_Alternative(ccTag As String)

       Dim cc As ContentControl
       Set cc = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag(ccTag).Item(1)

       With cc

           .LockContentControl = False
           .LockContents = False

           .Range.Delete               'to delete CC content

           .Delete (False)
       End With
   End Sub
   ```
3. `CC.Delete` in your code deletes only `ContentControl objects` itself but not its content. To delete content you need to add additional line which I did in my code above.

Comment: It seems like my error was because I accidentally had saved the file with the content control successfully deleted at some point (but with the same error message because of a whitespace problem for another CC).

This was a sleek and nice solution though! Nice to see I wasn't all wrong. To not remove the contents of the content control is intentional, because I intend to use the content itself to find and delete the cell/row it is located in.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment to KazJaw's answer but I don't have the rep.

According to Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194849(v=office.15).aspx), if you pass True to the Delete method it removes both the content control and its contents.

So: just get the Item as KazJaw showed, without jumping through the hoop of getting its ID:

```
Set cc = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag(ccTag).Item(1)
```

then call .Delete(True) on it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However the intention is to only delete the content control (actually mostly just to unlock it) so that I can remove the entire row or cell that the CC and its content exist in, and I use the text inside the CC to locate the cell/row (it is also what generates the tag string to search for the CC by)