# Word VBA to delete Content Controls with specific Tags

Tags: vba, ms-word

I read the answers to the question on [How to find and disable a content control by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199398/how-to-find-and-disable-a-content-control-by-tag-to-delete-it-and-its-contents) on SO (below is the code for your convenience). In my case, I need to delete Content Controls (CC) with SPECIFIC tags.

For Example, out of the 150 **`CCs`** that I have in the document, I need to find and delete only those **`CCs`** with the Tag **`"DCC"`**(just the CC, not its contents). As you can tell, I have no/limited experience in VB and would greatly appreciate a script that I can copy/paste.

I'm using Rich Text CCs in Word 2007.

```
Private Sub DeleteCCByTag_Alternative(ccTag As String)

    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Set cc = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag(ccTag).Item(1)

    With cc

        .LockContentControl = False
        .LockContents = False

        .Range.Delete               'to delete CC content

        .Delete (False)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to figure out ONE way of doing this....not the prettiest code and I'm sure there's a better way to do this. But, with my extremely limited VB knowledge, the below is working for my needs:

```
Sub DeleteCCByTag()
Dim oThisdoc As Word.Document
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Dim oCCs As ContentControls

Set oThisdoc = ActiveDocument
Set oCCs = oThisdoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("DCC")

    For Each oCC In oCCs
    If oCCs.Count > 0 Then
    oCC.Delete False
End If
Next
End Sub
```