# Removing Content Controls from an Outlook MailItem using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

When writing a macro that utilizes email templates uploaded to a company SharePoint to draft emails to clients, I'm having difficulties with template that have Content Controls. So far, I've been getting around this issue by simply replacing the text that displays in the Content Control with " ". However, if you hover your mouse over it, you can see the Content Control box, and if it's clicked on or otherwise accidentally selected, the text "Choose an item." or similar will reappear. Macros in Outlook are disabled by company policy, so all of this is being done in Excel. It's also in an HTML format, if that makes a difference for this functionality. Is there a vba command that I can use to remove the content controls of an email body?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a vba command that I can use to remove the content controls of an email body?

It seems you just need to edit the message body. The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the MailItem class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the HTMLBody property will always update the `Body` property immediately.
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information. The Word object model has everything you need to deal with content controls:

```
Dim objCC As ContentControl

For Each objCC In Document.ContentControls
  objCC.Delete True
Next
```

Take a look at the [Is there any method or macro to remove all content controls in MS Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162589/is-there-any-method-or-macro-to-remove-all-content-controls-in-ms-word) and [Word VBA to delete Content Controls with specific Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989926/word-vba-to-delete-content-controls-with-specific-tags) pages.

Note, the [MailItem.BodyFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-bodyformat-property-outlook) property allows you to programmatically change the editor that is used for the body of an item.